# Add files to the folder in a github repo via google colab

Tags: git, github, google-colaboratory

As I explained in the title, how can I upload the codes I have developed via google colab directly to any folder in a github repo, not a github repo? Because in the steps specified in the options, files can only be added to a specific repo, not to a directory of we want. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you click **Copy to GitHub** from the file options, select the relevant repo from the tab that opens. Then add the file you created on Google Colab to the directory you want in GitHub by typing directory_name/file_name in the ***file path*** section.